# Search box in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse, it would bring up a search-box asking for the term, etc.
That's annoying because if I'm on a small monitor, the pop-up would cover most of the text.

Does Eclipse have a search-bar at the bottom  (or top) of the editor like Netbeans does?
(In Netbeans, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, a very small search-bar would appear at the bottom/top of the editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Increment find for this. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Then observe in the status bar THAT incremental find is activated. Then you can go on typing your search term the first occurrence of word will be highlighted in editor if found else you will get `<search term> is not found error`(in red colour) in status bar.

Refer the image below
[image]

Note:

1. You can cycle through forward the next occurrences by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and backward by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. If the shortcut key for incremental find is NOT working then check the short cut keys for `Increment Find` and `Reverse incremental Find` commands in 
   `Windows->Preferences->Keys` section

Comment: Unfortuntely this doesn't have the luxury of selecting case-sensitive, whole word, etc.