# Find/Replace Bar in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been programming in Netbeans for 3 years and now I have to change to Eclipse.
One of the things that bothers me is the find/replace dialog.
I would like to install a plugin that permits me to use a bar instead a dialog.

I found one in Marketplace, but, unfortunately, I have to use Eclise Galileo, that don't have support to marketplace.

I found this one http://sandipchitaleseclipseplugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FindReplaceBarUpdateSite/, but when I try to install it occurs time out.

Do you know a find bar plugin that I can install in eclipse galileo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Find/Replace bar in eclipse. But you can use Incremental find/Reverse incremental find. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21771874/1391924) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find some text & when done hit esc.  This will close find/replace window & clear view for your editor.

Also you can use combination of word select commands and 
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd>).

This should save you installing plugin.